# Sample project for Telerik RadGrid using DropDown for Edit/Insert

Tags: telerik, radgrid

I am badly stuck with using DropDown for Edit/Insert in RadGrid. So far I have been successful in displaying data in dropDown inside RadGrid, but not being able to Update to database. While trying to update, I keep getting error:

Telerik.web.UI.GridException "Cannot find a cell bound to a columns name 'XXXX'

Also we cannot use sqldatasource for security purposes. I searched a lot but can't find solution. If someone could provide me with a working code it will be very helpful.

Comment: Long answer short, No! All important informations are missing. Your car don't work. The warning is ...ok but What car model? Can we see the car at least? What fuel do you use? Jet fuel bio fuel? Have you try something to fix it? May we see what you try? So we can't give you detail on working car. We won't know what point to explain. Please, [edit] your question to be a [mcve]. We need at least: Version of telerik. Grid declaration, edit column declaration, datasource, edit mode.

Comment: Here is [offical demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-editing/automatic-crud-operations/defaultcs.aspx) on Grid data editing